# OneSignal/OneSignal.h file not found on xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, onesignal

I am using xcode 12.4 (latest) and i am newbie. While building, i am getting the following error. I have examined the error on stackoverflow from the previous questions but i couldn't find a solution. Could you tell me what i need to do?

```
'OneSignal/OneSignal.h' file not found
 1. Did not find header 'OneSignal.h' in framework 'OneSignal' (loaded from '/Users/m/Desktop/ios_source.tar/ios_source/ios/Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Framework')
```